# Can 影響がある・する be used to express all the concepts of 'influencing', 'inspiring' and 'affecting'?

Tags: nuances, expressions

See these example sentences:

> 1. Xsan's beautiful pictures inspired me to start traveling.
> 2. Who influenced your painting technique the most?
> 3. What factors affected your decision to become an artist?

Can 影響がある (or possibly 影響する) be used in all these cases, or are there better options for some of them (eg. for inspiring)?

Also, is there a big difference between 影響がある and 影響する? A previous thread ([Differences between する, 及ぼす, 与える with 影響?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/differences-between-%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-%e5%8f%8a%e3%81%bc%e3%81%99-%e4%b8%8e%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b-with-%e5%bd%b1%e9%9f%bf)) suggested that 影響する has a stronger meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

影響 is not enough to express "inspire", which is kind of difficult to directly translate. I'd render the first sentence into something like Xさんの美しい絵を見て、旅を始めたくなった or …始めようと思った.

For the rest, you can use 影響がある like 2. ご自身の絵の技術に最も影響があったのは誰ですか？ and 3. 何の影響があって芸術家になろうと決めたんですか？ or 何の影響で芸術家に….

And there's not a big difference between 影響がある and 影響する. If any, the latter takes the factor as the subject, hence, feels more direct.